# class_exists returns true but still getting a Class not found error

Tags: php

```
if (class_exists('PhpThumb')) {
  $pt = PhpThumb::getInstance();
  $pt->registerPlugin('GdReflectionLib', 'gd');
}


if (in_array('PhpThumb', get_declared_classes())) {
  $pt = PhpThumb::getInstance();
  $pt->registerPlugin('GdReflectionLib', 'gd');
}
```

Either of these codes blocks throw the following error: "PHP Fatal error: Class 'PhpThumb' not found"

Can anyone explain why?  Is this a bug in PHP?

Comment: Do you have a custom autoloader?  An autoloader that fails to load a class without throwing an error would probably produce this.

Comment: This is in a third-party library that I've used before and never seen this issue.  I'll see if there's an autoloader.  However, `get_defined_classes` also includes PhpThumb in the array so I'm assuming it shouldn't have to go through an autoloader.

Comment: @frank-farmer Followup: I mean **`get_declared_classes`**

Comment: `class_exists` is case insensitive, so it is possible, however unlikely, thet a different class with the same case-insensitive name does exist. It has been suggested to use `in_array( 'PhpThumb', get_declared_classes() ) )`.

Comment: @MasterAm I just tried that code and it's throwing the same error.  I'll modify the question to clarify, though.

Comment: I have the same problem. Bump.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same bug. In my case problem was due to mixed Russian and English letters in class name which looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

I had a legacy code running under a newer version of PHP (5.3.10). I had some require_once() statements that was not doing their job. As I could change, I changed them do include() and it worked again.

I guess it have something to do with the PHP version, because running under a previous version the website was ok.

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me when I was requiring a file not needed by a phpunit class I was running.  The file was there, but I got the error.

Yet for a test that ***does*** need that class, the same include call works.

My work around was to have 2 config files, where 1 requires that class file and the 2nd file doesn't.  So when not needed, I use the latter.

A little clunky with 1 extra small file *(that I shouldn't have to create .. cse' la vie)*, but unblocks the issue here

Answer (score 0):

After spending few hours on practicing with this mistakefullish fatal error...I've admitted that this function doesn't work with SPL autoload! And I've finally found a solution :
I replace 'class_exists()' by 'file_exists()' with a little bit more process to find out the real path of the class file (my classes have the same name as their filename).
Hope it helps.